# PHP url call in ajax does not execute - success not triggered

Tags: php, ajax, directory, path

ISSUE: Ajax php script not being called. It does not trigger the success response. It triggers error.

General idea - creating a simple admin dashboard with php scripts.
Firstly - this is a code that **was working** when all files were in the directory localhost/admin

i wanted to remove .php from the urls when accessing them on the browser and created individual folders for each function and renamed the main file of each folder to index.php

For example - for function country -

Folder country

inside folder scripts - index.php, country_row.php,country_add.php,country_delete.php

form submit for add - WORKS!!

AJAX call to retrieve the information of each row ID - DOES NOT WORK. Please help me where i am going wrong. all other php call scripts works except for ajax php scripts. how to specify the directory properly?

```js
function getRow(id){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'country/country_row.php',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        alert("hi");
      $("input[type=text][name=countryid]").val(response.country_id);
      $("[name='country']").html(response.country);
    
    },
   error: function()
   {
    alert("error");
   }
  });
}
```

in the header file i provided the base href as below. Only when giving so - my css links and script links work as expected from all folders and subfolders.

```html
<base href="/admin/">
```

country_row.php script is below:

```
<?php 
include '../includes/session.php';
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    
    $conn = $pdo->open();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(['id'=>$id]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    
    $pdo->close();
    
 echo json_encode($row);
}
```

?>

Edit -
My response tab from dev tools shows the record being pulled successfully. but the success function still does not trigger.

[image]

Comment: Use your browser's DevTools/Console/Network tab to see if the url gets called. If your files reside in `/admin/country/country_row.php` use this path in your JS

Comment: Yes in my dev tools network tab country_row.php gets called. Also in apache access.log, it shows its calling it without any error entry into error.log. when i change the path in url to only country_row.php, it adds an error in error.log that it cannot be found.

Comment: Also tried specifying the current path and url like this var parentUrl = window.location.href;
 url = parentUrl + 'country_row.php';  - and sending this url to ajax. It does not trigger success function. Triggers error function

Comment: try this
$stmt->execute([':id'=>$id]);

Comment: In your DevTools there should be "request" and "response" tabs where you can see what actually gets delivered by your script.

Comment: it shows the record being pulled out of the database successfully. But why wouldnt my success function be triggered?? I am confused on how to proceed

Comment: added the response as an image in my question.

Comment: an echo of hi and success from included php was making it trigger the error function. Now i feel silly. Thank you @brombeer, i found this by checking the response tab.